# Add hide or close button to the ten million question banner

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, 10m-questions-milestone

I love it here, really, and I spend a lot of time, but it's really annoying this banner showing a front of me all the time. I read it and I like it (some parts of it were funny) but can you please add an (X) or something to hide it ?

[image]

edit

its a controversial thing many people complained about it and many like it 15 votes up and 15 downvotes, thats why the (X) should be optional.

[image]

Comment: I'm extremely tempted to create a [meta-tag:we-hate-fun] tag for this question.

Comment: I am curious about the downvote I mean do you really like this banner a front of you all the time ?

Comment: Its not that bad, and celebrates a milestone in our community. I have no problem with it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET well I was searching now for 10 questions and everytime I see it at top. if you like it you can keep but for who don't can close it .

Comment: First thing I thought when I saw it: Wait, I've been logged out again, and am seeing banner ads? Away with it! …then I read the text :-)

Comment: It's also in the place where the duplicate banner normally appears, so I keep thinking that the question has been closed as a dupe.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET celebrate as much as you like - but that's not a good enough reason for a horrible UX! Simply make it closeable and everybody will be happy.

Comment: Man, if a gray box at the top of the page already annoys you, don't have children ;)

Comment: @Gimby if the point of UIs were to be "less annoying than having children" then that'd be an awesome point! Now you just need to write some articles convincing everyone that that's the way to go.

Comment: I am all for #we-hate-fun. I would upvote every post with this tag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I understand that once you've seen the message, you cannot hide it. So it can be annoying. I wrote this user script to hide system messages. <s>Just make sure to turn it off after the banner is removed.</s> It now tries to guess when the banner is gone and turn itself off, then prompt you to uninstall it.

If you have GreaseMonkey or TamperMonkey, you should be able to install it by simply visiting [this link](https://gist.github.com/Tiny-Giant/4697abdfe8e050b93d17/raw/7ebdcae3075f2d4026a038f0d03c287f6e613cef/SOHideSystemMessage.user.js)

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SO Hide system message
// @namespace    http://github.com/Tiny-Giant
// @version      0.1
// @description  Hide system messages on Stack Overflow
// @author       @TinyGiant
// @match        http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
    "use strict";
    if(!localStorage['SOHideSystemMessage_done']) {
        var m, interval = setInterval(function(){
            if(localStorage['SOHideSystemMessage_done']) clearInterval(interval);
            m = document.getElementById('system-message')
            if(m) if(m.firstChild.textContent === "Ten. Million. Questions. Let's celebrate ") {
                clearInterval(interval);
                document.head.innerHTML += '<style>#system-message { display: none; }</style>';
            } else localStorage['SOHideSystemMessage_done'] = true;
        });
    } else if(!localStorage['SOHideSystemMessage_ack']) {
        alert('The banner is gone, you should be able to remove this script now.');
        localStorage['SOHideSystemMessage_ack'] = true;
    }
})();
```

Comment: If I dont have the GreaseMOnkey or TamperMonkey , how to add them ?

Comment: Are you using chrome or firefox?

Comment: I am using firefox

Comment: Visit [the addon page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and install greasemonkey, then come back and visit the link in my answer.

Comment: I don't like addons however thanks for your solution.

Comment: Don't want greasemonkey script. Want "Do not show again" box.

Comment: @torazaburo Well, I cannot make Stack Exchange do anything they do not want to do, and basically what you want isn't going to happen. However, this is an alternative solution, if you want it.

Answer (score 11):

Nope.

**Billions** of times developers were well-served on SO is not something I'm inclined to dismiss. Why we do what we do might be obvious to you, it isn't for everyone, and the top of the page is quickly hidden once you start scrolling.

If it bothers you *that* much, just hide it, you can find quite a few ways of going about that on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I am not saying to remove it , all I am saying that after we read it if we can hide it ? what is the purpose of it staying a front of us after we know what is it ? its something related to User-Interface , and personaly I deslike it. and I gave my opinion. and its up to `them`

Comment: @Moudiz If you dislike it so much, use greasemonkey to remove it. I feel better knowing no dev time is spent to "fix" something that you can fix yourself if it aggravates you that much

Comment: @Patrice because of this discussion and  because I use meta I knew greasemonkey , but many user especially the new comers will not know that there is greasemonkey.or a trick.

Comment: @Moudiz True that, but for a banner that won't be permanent and is made to celebrate the achievement stack reached, I don't think wasting dev time to make it closable is worth it

Comment: @Patrice user-interface its a bit tricky. anyway I gave my opinion. thanks anyway

Comment: It's annoying. Annoying stuff is bad UX. Bad UX shouldn't survive. The way out is easy: MAKE IT CLOSEABLE.

Comment: @kleopatra "annoying" is subjective. Means meaningless as a guide good/bad anything. Presumably if it was desirable and achievable, they'd have done it.

Comment: @BillWoodger in UX, anything that disturbs the user is a very good reason _not_ to do it - "subjective" or not is completely irrelevant. User rules. Period.

Comment: @kleopatra No. Anyone can be "disturbed" by anything, because it is subjective. You'd never get anything done. You don't like it so much that it "disturbs" you, don't use the site for a week, and then a couple of days every week for the next four.

Comment: @BillWoodger a silver badge in ... cobol - that explains a lot ;-) SCNR - anyway "if you don't like the smell simply stop breathing" is not a solution.

Comment: @kleopatra you mean the compliment of a silver badge with only 730 questions to choose from, of course. Thanks, you're welcome.

Comment: SO just (finally) got around to improving the weird UX a bit. Saying "if you don't like it then script a way to remove it" may explain why it took so long :)

Comment: Wow, maybe there's a presidential campaign or something you can go to work for if you're able to spin "User wants to be able to close the box once they've seen it" into "User wants to blatantly ignore the wonderful accomplishments of SO". By the way, on the mobile version of SO, this message takes up something close to **10%** of the screen.